# post install class access modifier

Tags: managed-package, postinstall, delete-managed-package

Is there a reason for post install script to be global access? why not public? Any reasons for not making the postInstallClass public?
I ask because global classes cannot be deleted from managed packages later on.

Even in salesforce's example : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_post_install_script_create.htm

they are using global.

Comment: Salesforce docs use the global modifier all over where it is neither required nor even beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce docs tends to write examples that use `global` despite not needing to. From time to time, I've seen this on scheduled classes, batchable classes, queueable classes, etc. You should not generally follow this example. Basically, you should instead consider the purpose of the class at hand.

If it's in your *own* org, it should be `public`, unless the compiler specifically tells you something must be `global`. If it's in a managed package to be installed, it should be `public` *unless* it is meant to be used directly by subscribers (the most usual case are utility classes for controlling behavior and scheduled classes that can be scheduled by the subscriber directly).

For all typical cases, you should assume that `public` is the correct access modifier, unless the documentation specifically says "the access modifier must be global" (e.g. [Considerations for Using the `webservice` Keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods_considerations.htm) says "All classes that contain methods defined with the webservice keyword must be declared as global"), or it is a feature meant to be directly used by subscribers.

When in doubt, make your code `public` or `private`. You can always promote it to `global` later if you realize you made a mistake, but you can't go back down once you do go `global`. Post-install handlers are one of those times where it typically doesn't make sense to have it be `global`, because it may expose underlying data structures or secrets you don't want exposed unnecessarily.