# How to Fix Security Violation AvoidGlobalModifier in a Promoted 2GP Managed Package for the Security Review

Tags: managed-package, security-review, 2gp, second-generation-packaging

I did wrong and I promoted a non-security-review-ready version in a managed package.

I have a global identifier and if I try to create a new version without the it, it triggers a `Global/WebService identifiers cannot be removed from managed application:`.
If I roll back to the `global` identifier I start getting the `AvoidGlobalModifier`;`Avoid using global modifier` violation. It is a severity level 3.

Could you please share what are my options to pass the security review for this violation?

**Update 1** :
When I requested a rollback in a Support Case I was redirected to [Revert Second-Generation (2GP) Managed Package to Beta](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381270&type=1)

and [Use Branches in Second-Generation Managed Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_use_branches.htm)

Then I manually added in my `sfdx-project.json` file:

- 1st a package alias

```
  "packageAliases": {
    "myPackage@4.0.0.2-rc2": "04t7R0000018v4SQAQ", // this is the released one
    "myPackage@4.0.0.1-rc1": "04t7R0000018unhQAA", // this is the one that I target to be the parent
    "myPackage@4.0.0.0-rc0": "04t7R0000018uncQAA",
  }
```

- 2nd I added a dependency to my package definition:

```
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "myPackage",
      "versionName": "myPackage-4.1.0",
      "versionNumber": "4.1.0.NEXT",
      "branch": "rc3",
      "versionDescription": "myPackage",
      "dependencies": [
        {
          "package": "myPackage@4.0.0.1-rc1"
        }]
    },
```

- 3rd I ran the sf package version create

```
sf package version create -p "myPackage" -c -t="G4E-6527 at git commit afb6387" -b=G4E-6527 -x --post-install-script PostInstallScript --post-install-url "https://docs.glue42.com/connectors/salesforce-connector/installation-and-configuration/index.html#custom_metadata_types-visual_url" --verbose -a=myPackage-4.1.0.2-rc3  --skipancestorcheck
```

- The Error are all about the same:

```
Warning: (1) MyCustomAction: Cannot modify managed object: entity=AuraDefinitionBundle, component=0Ab5t000000Xbgu, field=BundleType, state=installed
```

- 4th I have  updated my package definition once again:

```
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "myPackage",
      "ancestorVersion": "NONE",
      "versionName": "myPackage-4.1.0",
      "versionNumber": "4.1.0.NEXT",
      "branch": "rc3",
      "versionDescription": "myPackage"
    },
```

**Update2**: Now, I encounter the following errors in almost all of my Tests during package version creation:

```
System.QueryException: No such column 'External_Field_Name__c' on entity 'myNS__Mapping__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: Globals are permitted and indeed needed in managed packages if you need to expose a class or set of methods for use by subscribers. They are generally not required otherwise.

Comment: If you have not got the version introducing the global installed anywhere you can ask Salesforce Support to revert it back to beta then you can remove the global if you do not need it.

Comment: oh, that sounds good. it is not shared with anyone yet. I have my PostInstall script declared as global, but seems I don't need to have it as global to run, doesn't it?

Comment: No need to be global, as discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200634/post-install-class-access-modifier).

Comment: The errors you list - have you got the scratch org defined to use your package's namespace prefix? With package version creation a temporary "packaging org" is created for 2GP (effectively an "internal only" scratch org) so you need to make sure your scratch def and project JSONs are appropriate for this usage.

Comment: oh, I thought creating the scratch Orgs is going to complicate the process only :(. So, I have only used my Dev Hub Developer Edition Org for development.
Can I do something to fix that?

Comment: You really must use scratch orgs for 2GP development; this is what they are designed to support. There are some complexities (specifically around if you have dependencies you need to install) but scratch orgs can share the package's namespace. You have to have the `config/project-scratch-def.json` and `sfdx-project.json` files so package version creation can succeed, so you should adopt best practice. You can read around this [over here](https://ktema.org/articles/understanding-build-orgs-environmental-dependencies/). This is very detailed but will help with understanding.

Comment: Hey Phil, I have one more question: If these errors are only in the Test classes does it mean that I need to move my test classes into an unpackaged meta separate package?

Comment: 2GP supports having an extra folder with metadata that supports unit testing but that is not part of the package. However, AFAIK, you are still expected to include the actual unit tests in the package itself.

Comment: I see these last errors in my Tests, the mentioned column and object are in the main managed package, so IMO this error is not expected. Let me know where I'm wrong.

Comment: I think you raised a new question for that, right? (Which is a good idea.)

Comment: Yep, I saw that deploying the same code to one of my older Dev Hubs trigger the same Test errors.

Comment: for those interested https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/411111/128410

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working on a 1GP, you simply need to:

1. Ensure the version(s) of the package containing the spurious global modifiers are not installed anywhere,
2. Raise a [Salesforce Support case](https://help.salesforce.com/s/cases) to ask for them to revert these version(s) to beta and
3. Replace the global modifiers and create a replacement version of your package as desired.

With 2GP, you just need to [abandon that version branch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_ancestors.htm), creating a new version with an appropriate ancestor that omits this undesired change. Clearly, anyone with the abandoned version installed will be unable to upgrade since that version won't be an ancestor of any later development, but hopefully no one is using it. You'll find some more info around ancestry [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_upgrades.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately support had answered that "The revert to beta process is used for making changes to published 1GP packages only." And they forwarded me to Revert Second-Generation (2GP) Managed Package to Beta
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381270&type=1. Which leads to another package of version creation errors.... I would see what else I could provide in Description related to my branching experience...

Comment: With 2GP you should be able to simply dead-end that "bad" version and create a new one with an appropriate ancestor. I suggest you engage with the wider [partner community for Managed Packages](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HXAq) if you are struggling with that.

Comment: I have updated the details in the Description, Could you please elaborate on how to do the dead-end that "bad" version? Or you refer to creating a new package directly?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some links to explanations around 2GP versioning, ancestry and version branching. Dead-ending is simply where you do not use the "bad" version as the ancestor of any other versions. I hope the linked documentation helps you understand this better.

Comment: I've recognized that my problem has been promoting my initial version for the 2GP package with the globals.

Comment: You hadn't changed the `sfdx-project.json`?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get your question. What I was trying to say is that my initial package version included a lot of globals, which I have removed recently. Turns out my problem with that managed package is that I've promoted one of my 6 versions with globals. So there's no previous promoted version without the globals to take as an ancestor. (I'm doing a rebranding of a package and getting it ready for security review, so a lot of issues within the CodeScanner reports had to be fixed)

Comment: That suggests you need to create a new version, without any ancestor, and deprecate the other one(s).

Comment: If I use --skip-ancestor-check it want a higher number, so I guess the new version is not an option. I need a new package.